# Error en SimpleExcel.php

Tags: php, excel

Buen día, estoy intentando exportar un excel desde la librería `SimpleExcel.php` usando la carpeta test descargado desde su [sitio web oficial](http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-php/) pero me indica el siguiente error al ejecutar el archivo `test/HTML/HTMLTest.php`

> Warning: require_once(D:\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\dev\simple-excel-php-master\src\SimpleExcel\ework_TestCase.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\dev\simple-excel-php-master\src\SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel.php on line 43
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\dev\simple-excel-php-master\src\SimpleExcel\ework_TestCase.php' (include_path='D:\OneDrive\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\dev\simple-excel-php-master\src\SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel.php on line 43

Ayuda por favor, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que hay en esa linea 43??

Comment: ¿Verificaste si la carpeta `D:\OneDrive\xampp\htdocs\dev\simple-excel-php-master\src\SimpleExcel\` y archivo `SimpleExcel.php` existen?

Comment: Hola Mauricio, todo esta correcto, puedes descargarte la carpeta del ejemplo y probar si deseas.

Comment: Podrias añadir la linea de codigo fuente donde se ejecuta require_once a tu pregunta?